# How to write and read NSAttributedstring to and from an XML file?

Tags: objective-c, xml, xml-parsing, nsstring, nsattributedstring

I am trying to write an attributed string to an XML File and later I try to read it out of there. I have found out all values that I read from NSXMLParser are of type NSMutableString.

I was wondering how to save the Attributed String to the XML File and how to read it back in the most effective way.

I have been flirting with the idea of saving the attributes and text separately in the text of XML and then get the strings back and build back the NSAttributedString object. Is this the best possible way? hell- is this even possible this way?

Comment: I am honestly not too familiar with using `NSXMLParser` but off the top of my head if you can use `NSData` objects (which it seems you can using the `initWithData:` method) you should be able to convert your `NSAttributedString` to data using `dataFromRange:documentAttributes:error:` and store that in XML. If that doesn't work, you can of course also just store the attributes manually and handle your own serialization as you said, which I think is a perfectly acceptable way of doing it.